# How i can display only products uploaded by particular user?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

First, i say that i am new programming django with python. Sorry, if asked small problems. And also , its seems a long code, but very clean.

The problem I am facing that I want to display only user's products which is uploaded by him, not by admin or other user.
[[like a user using his dashboard and seeing his products and items .]]

Here is my models.py:

```
#Product details uploaded
class AffProduct(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    specification = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sale_price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    img1 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    img2 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    promote_method = models.TextChoices
    terms_conditions = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    promote_method = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=promote_choices,
        default='PPC'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'affiliation'
        db_table = 'affproduct'
        managed = False
```

Here views.py:

```
def AddNewProduct(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product_title =request.POST['product_title']
        uid = request.POST['uid']
        specification =request.POST['specification']
        sale_price = request.POST['sale_price']
        discount = request.POST['discount']
        img1 = request.FILES['img1']
        img2 = request.FILES['img2']
        promote_method = request.POST['promote_method']
        terms_conditions = request.POST['terms_conditions']
        newproduct = AffProduct(product_title=product_title, uid=uid, specification=specification, sale_price=sale_price,
                                discount=discount, img1=request.FILES.get('img1'), img2=request.FILES.get('img2'),
                                promote_method=promote_method, terms_conditions=terms_conditions)
        newproduct.save()

        ##** Here I am trying to fetch products uploaded by the particular user,So i can display products for particular user.{It,s like user using his dashboard to do operations}**##
        #newproduct["seller"] = AffProduct.objects.get(pk=request.loginid)
        # Status message
        messages.success(request, 'Product added successfully')

        return render(request, 'blink_network.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'blink_network.html')

def showproduct(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        result = AffProduct.objects.all()
    else:
        result = AffProduct.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blink_viewproduct.html', {'result':result})
```

Comment: Your mjodel does not have a column that is a `ForeignKey` to the user model?

Comment: user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: but why is this not part of your model?

Comment: I would also advise to work with a Django *form* to validate and clean the input.

Comment: I am new to django. I am doing bit by bit . After creating the model, I have tried adding this to my model, but no migrations is happening

Comment: u r telling about adding forms.py to my app

Comment: what should i add to my view then? @w

Comment: First you should declare a field in your model by which you can identify who is the creater of product.Then in your view you have to filter out products created by only that particular user..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#so first add user entry in AffProductmodel

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class AffProduct(models.Model):
    #user entry
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    specification = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sale_price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    img1 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    img2 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    promote_method = models.TextChoices
    terms_conditions = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    promote_method = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=promote_choices,
        default='PPC'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'affiliation'
        db_table = 'affproduct'
        managed = False
```

#now save user when user upload product

```
def AddNewProduct(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        product_title =request.POST['product_title']
        uid = request.POST['uid']
        specification =request.POST['specification']
        sale_price = request.POST['sale_price']
        discount = request.POST['discount']
        img1 = request.FILES['img1']
        img2 = request.FILES['img2']
        promote_method = request.POST['promote_method']
        terms_conditions = request.POST['terms_conditions']
        #while saving we  add here owner of product via request.user
        newproduct = AffProduct(owner=request.user,product_title=product_title, uid=uid, specification=specification, sale_price=sale_price,
                                discount=discount, img1=request.FILES.get('img1'), img2=request.FILES.get('img2'),
                                promote_method=promote_method, terms_conditions=terms_conditions)
        newproduct.save()

        ##** Here I am trying to fetch products uploaded by the particular user,So i can display products for particular user.{It,s like user using his dashboard to do operations}**##
        #newproduct["seller"] = AffProduct.objects.get(pk=request.loginid)
        # Status message
        messages.success(request, 'Product added successfully')

        return render(request, 'blink_network.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'blink_network.html')
```

```
show product on page , here if user authenticated so we only filter out #those product whose owner logged user ,  
    
    def showproduct(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            result = AffProduct.objects.fiter(owner=request.user)
        else:
            result = AffProduct.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blink_viewproduct.html', {'result':result})
```

Comment: ERRORS:
affiliation.AffProduct.owner: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
I am encountering this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'filter()'.

```py
queryset = AffProduct.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

But to do that, you will need to add

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```